# Why is px often prefered over pt even though both depend on an "unknown" device parameter?

Tags: fonts, website-design, screen-size

I always heard that in web design one should *not* prefer `pt` as a size unit, because the browser/OS does not neccessarily know the correct `dpi`. Result: final font sizes are not equal on different computers (Mac and Windows have different default `dpi`, for example).

But isn't this true for the "prefered" `px` as well? If I buy a FullHD monitor with 20" diameter and a FullHD monitor with 40" diameter, the font sizes will differ by a factor of two, because the physical pixel sizes are twice the size on the bigger monitor compared to the smaller one. So, for `px` I have the same effect, because the browser does not know the device size.

Conclusion: If I take a ruler and measure a `pt` based font on two different devices I can get different results (unknown real `dpi` size). But for sure I can get different results for a `px` based font size as well just because the same-resolution-device is bigger/smaller (unknown real physical pixel size).

**So, why is the "unknown device parameter argument" used for `pt` but not for `px`?**

---

*Bonus question:* why do devices not deliver their physical size information via its device driver to the OS, anyways? A device should know how big it is and how much physical pixels it has, because someone build it with a defined size and pixel density and could just store this in the firmware.

Comment: As for physical size, there is a problem with projectors.  The size changes based on how close the projector is to the wall.  Even if there were a built in default size, it wouldn't be appropriate to use for web page development. `max-width: 12in` would be ridiculously small projected on a wall while being pretty big for most monitors.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Shouldn't a projector (approximately) being able to calculate the distance to the wall on the fly by using the lense parameters (e.g. focal length), assuming the user adjusts these parameters correctly to make the image appear sharp?

Comment: First, that technology would have to be built into technology.   While it sounds possible, it might make projectors more expensive.   I don't know that any projectors currently do it.   Then it would have to be able to communicate that information back to the computer.   I'm not sure that DVI or HDMI would even support that.  Then the computer would have to make that information available to the software.   Even if all that happened, I don't think it would be useful information.   Generally you use a projector because you want them blown up so everybody can see.

Comment: Actually, this technology exists since 1994: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel - questions is, why it is not used widely. Anyways, this was just a bonus question, the main question assumes that this data exchange is not possible or not used.

Comment: Are you talking device pixels or CSS pixels? They are not the same. There IS a formula for pixels as defined by the W3C and applies to the web. But it's too much for me to go into here and I think this may be off topic.

Comment: @Rob I thought they are the same. But I just looked in the official W3C CSS2 docs about unit lengths (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units) and there's just stated that `1px = 0.75pt` and a `pt` is just 1/72", so I'm starting to wonder if there's a really a fundamental difference between them at all. So If I multiply all my `px` values with 0.75 and change `px` to `pt`, will the output change on any device?

Comment: So the question maybe really is: do browsers treat `px` and `pt` really differently (appart from the 0.75 factor)? Assuming with `pt` they consider the `dpi` setting from the OS, what "base length" do they take for `px`, do they also just use the `dpi`? If not, what else do they take to determine the size of a CSS pixel (that I can measure with a real phyiscal ruler on my display)?

Comment: Still no time to go into this but this may help: http://inamidst.com/stuff/notes/csspx There are articles on the web about pixels, CSS pixels, device pixels. Group them together and do a search.

Comment: Well, my devices do not track my distance to them to adjust the font sizes accordingly ;) (also this contradicts the statement that `1px = 0.75pt` if `pt` is fixed to the inch and `px` is dependend on the distance of the eye). I have a math background, I can do such calculations easily. The question remains, what calculations based on what variables/values/constants the browsers actually do internally to render an object with size `1pt` vs. `1px`.

Comment: But no matter what a CSS pixel is: In the very end the browser has to do one important thing: map CSS pixels (or whatever) to physical pixels of my monitor (because this is the thing I am looking at). And it does not know the size of my physical pixel - all it can use to do so is either guess wildly or use the OS setting with the name `dpi`. So I still don't get why `pt` should be worse than `px`. IMHO they are both equally "bad" because they depend, after all, on the same unknown parameter (real physical pixel size).

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I hope i got this right, seems like the point (DPI) is more volatile to digital display environment whereas a pixel is more static.

A `pt` is much older and comes from the print/lithography era. Classically it is 1/72 of an inch. So in that regard an inch is an inch is an inch...except when it goes digital. In order for a device to deduce what an inch is, it must know its own pixel size, pixel density, resolution, physical size, relativity, etc. These are 4-5 factors of "device parameters" that affect the "real world parameter" of an baseline inch in a conditional(ish) manner. A point could equal 20 pixels or a point could equal 200 pixels, depending on device, but it is always equiv to 1/72 of an inch (which is why you often see 72 DPI for digi displays).

A `px` is more simple: its a pixel without regard for density, inches, etc. This means that there are no "device parameters" to affect the conditional calculation of said `px`. Retina seems like it would be different, but its not, its still just a pixel in a normal-density alpha transparency layer. The retina layer is separated thang that doesnt really affect the proportions of `px` itself. So 20 pixels could equal 1 point (dot) or 200 pixels could equal 1 point (dot), but 1 pixel is always equivalent to 1 pixel.

As far as the bonus question goes, I think it comes down to: "*Life is unfair, get over it. Just kidding. We werent thinking too hard about the future and didnt expect multi-device resolution to become such a critical thing, therefore didnt worry about coding up good identifiers for developers to use. We have started to get better at this and are now sharing some better data from screens*"